# Saxon-PE 9.9.1.7 : Integer division by zero

Tags: xslt, saxon, oxygenxml

While I'm trying to update a `xsl` file with Oxygen XML that I haven't touched in three years, this is the error message I get:

> [Saxon-PE 9.9.1.7] Integer division by zero

The results display correctly online with the version from three years ago--but even if I try to apply the transformation from the old version, I get the same error.
An example of encoding among a long list of such issues on integer:

```
<xsl:value-of
    select="format-number(count(
       //$clanA-aff/key('name', @xml:id)[@cert]
       | //$clanA-aff/key('name-same', @xml:id)[@cert]
       | //$clanA-aff/key('w-ana', @xml:id)[@cert]
       | //$clanA-aff/key('w-same1', @xml:id)[@cert]
       | //$clanA-aff/key('w-same2', @xml:id)[@cert])
       div $count-all,
       '#.00%')"
     />
```

Maybe the stylesheet information needs to be updated?

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:xd="http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array"
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs tei xsl math map array" version="3.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat"/>
    <xsl:param name="f2" select="'KTU_XInclude.xml'"/>
    <xsl:param name="f3" select="'taxonomy.xml'"/>

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <-- data -->
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The update I'm trying to do has nothing to do with this issue.
I have made no changes in the `xml` file in which the data are stored since years.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Post a [mcve] that illustrates the problem.  We obviously can't trust statements like *The update I'm trying to do has nothing to do with this issue* anymore than we can discern why `$count-all` is `0` when you've not shown us the code that sets `$count-all`.

Comment: You need to supply enough information to enable someone to reproduce the problem. I usually prefer to diagnose such problems based only on the current state of play, I rarely find that information about the history helps much. It certainly doesn't help to know that it worked on a previous version when you don't even tell us which version that was.

Comment: You are dividing by a numeric value called `$count-all`, which presumably equals `0`, but you haven't shown where that value is set, so there's no way for us to tell what the cause of your problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your answers. After new investigation, especially to give you a minimal example as requested, I realized that I had omitted the `XInclude` in the `XML` URL in the transformation process--my old Mac had crashed and when importing the files, I only omitted to take into account the XInclude knowing that I had not touched the encoding of this file nor Oxygen for several years--, I had only put the `XML` URL of the referenced file (`Character.xml`), so obviously all `key` could not work since they are related to descendants in other files inside the `XInclude`:

```
<div1>
   <stage>
     <xi:include xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" href="Character.xml"/>
   </stage>
</div1>
<div1 xml:lang="uga" xml:id="ktu1" type="transcription">
     <xi:include xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" href="KTU1.xml"/>
     <xi:include xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" href="KTU2.xml"/>
     <xi:include xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" href="KTU3.xml"/>
 </div1>
```

Everything works correctly now after adding in `XML` URL `${pdu}/uga/KTU_XInclude.xml`. It's a silly mistake but unfortunately I guess it can happen to anyone--I apologize for this oversight. Maybe this answer will allow others to make sure they have checked the `XML` URL of the transformation process before getting in a panic... if they get the same error message.

Once again thank you all!